# Global values of application and applet

Tags: java, variables, applet, global, next-generation-plugin

With desktop applications, to maintain global values, I usually have some singleton or static properties. However, recent days, I have been working with applet. And it causes some trouble because when I we open the application in different tabs of Firefox, the applets are launched in the same JVM and share the sames static things.

I wonder how you do manage global values in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to maintain global values? Likely you could rewrite it so the data is not global and simply avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applets running in a [Next Generation Java Plug-in Technology](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/newapplets/) JRE, it is easy.

```
<param name="separate_jvm" value="true" />
```